# How do I open separate tabs/windows for all buffers in Vim?

Tags: vim

How do I easily open my current vim buffers/arguments in a separate window/tab each?

I know about:

```
$ vim one.txt two.txt three.txt -O
```

However if I simply start vim with:

```
$ vim one.txt two.txt three.txt
```

How can I replicate this behaviour once I've already started vim?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To split all buffers use `:sba` or `:vert sba`

Answer (score 4):

Vim command `:sba` has also a shortcut: `:ba`.

> :[N]ba[ll] [N]
>   :[N]sba[ll] [N] Rearrange the screen to open one window for each buffer in the buffer list.

To back again to single tag, use: `:on` (`:only`).

> :on[ly][!]      Make the current window the only one on the screen. All other windows are closed.

To quit, use: `:qa`

See also: [How to convert all windows into horizontal, vertical or tab splits?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/758/467) at Vim SE

Answer (score 3):

How to convert buffers to windows/tabs:

- buffers > horizontal windows: `:ba` (buffer all)
- buffers > vertical windows: `:vert ba` (vertical buffer all)
- buffers > tabs: `:tab ba` (tab buffer all)

How to convert window/tabs to buffers:

- windows > buffers: `:on`, `:only` (current window only)
- tabs > buffers: `:tabo`, `:tabonly` (current tab only)

If you want to convert all windows to tabs, first convert windows to buffers, then buffers to tabs:

`:on | tab ba`

Answer (score 1):

Answering part of my own question:

How do I easily open my current vim <s>buffers/</s>arguments in a separate <s>window/</s>tab each?

```
:tab all
```